# How to send app invitation from my app in Android?

Tags: android

I am new in Android and working on a simple chat app. In my app I have to invite friends who are not currently using my app. My query is how to send app invitation from my app by only simple default message app in Android. I don't want to use any of already installed app for example: facebook, whatsapp, hike, gmail etc.
I have used this below code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to send SMS:

```
     Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:"); 
     Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri); 
     it.putExtra("sms_body", "Here you can set the SMS text to be sent"); 
     startActivity(it);
```

Comment: @SANJAYSHARMA, if it worked, please mark answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

So , you want to naviage the user with to default Message app of phone with intent.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:0800000123");   
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);   
it.putExtra("sms_body", "YOUR_PLAY_STORE_URL");   
startActivity(it);
```

or try with SmsManager

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
```